# Relative colour changing

Tags: python, colors, pygame, rgb

**Situation**

So I'm working on some buttons for a menu and I'm using functions to simplify the process.
When I call the function there's 9 parameters for the type I'm having trouble with:

```
def toggleButton(msg, x, y, w, h, c1, c2, toggle, boo):
```

But all we need for my question here are the parameters c1 and c2.
In simplest terms, they're the colours the button will be at each binary state.

Inside the function there's a linking variable "colour"
At each toggle state colour swaps between c1 and c2

**Problem**

Now that we have a context, my question is how could I change the values of c1 and c2 independently of actual knowledge of colour?

```
c1 = (r, g, b)
```

and then I turn c1 into:

```
c1 = (r+10, g+10, b+10)
```

without having to know (r, g, b) initially?

I tried using c1[0] which does output r but doesn't allow me to change the value.

My test code to try to figure this out is:

```
colour = (255, 255, 255)      ##arbitrary colour
print(colour)                 ##print the colour, outputs (255, 255, 255)

print(colour[0])              ## print first number, outputs 255
colour[0] = colour[0] - 50    ## code breaks with error "TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment"
print(colour)
print(colour[0])
```

**EDIT**

I've gotten my answer to the above question but this is a problem I found, if the resultant colour for:

```
colour = tuple([c+50 for c in colour])
```

is invalid, it breaks (obviously)
I tried

```
for c in colour:
        if c > 255:
            colour[c] = tuple(255)
```

to fix this but it doesn't work, so if anyone can help me, this would be really useful for preventing errors in the future, especially as I don't know which colours will be chosen when my code is used in the final product.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't subtract an int from a tuple.  If you want to subtract 50 from each element of colour, you could use

```
colour = tuple([c-50 for c in colour])
```

If you want to add delta to each value, and constrain the result to be between 0 and 255, you can use

`colour = tuple([max(0, min(255, c+delta)) for c in colour])`

Comment: Thanks, I've never had to alter tuples before,  this is simpler than I thought it'd be so thanks heaps.

Comment: @user3759953 Glad to help.